# Variables not passed to view template

Tags: views, theming

Initially I implemented logic to show results summary inside the views template file

> realia-view-grid--apartments--listing-row-filtered.tpl

Since best practices is to implement it in the hook_preprocess_views_view, I moved the code there and simply print $summaryText inside the template which is coming from below pre process hook

```
function realia_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
  //do nothing if not interested view-display
  if ($variables['display_id'] !=  'listing_row_filtered') return;

  $view = $variables['view'];

  isset($view->exposed_input['field_location_tid'])?$ltid = $view->exposed_input['field_location_tid']:$ltid = 'All';

  //force to all if landing directly
  $city = taxonomy_term_load($view->exposed_input['field_city_tr_tid'])->name;
  $locationName = $ltid == 'All'?'':' in ' . taxonomy_term_load($view->exposed_input['field_location_tid'])->name;
  $resultText = "Properties in $city: Your search criteria matched $view->total_rows properties$locationName";
  $variables['summaryText'] = $resultText;

}
```

I am setting the variable $variables['summaryText'] in the hook and when I add dpm($variables) it is showing the variable also but its not being passed to template file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the Realia theme doing something elsewhere to have Views recognize a template that starts with `realia-view` instead of `views.....`?

Comment: yes, there are realia-view-gmap.tpl.php,reaila-view-grid.tpl.php, realia-view-grid--apartments--listings-row-filtered.tpl.php

Comment: right, and unless I am having a bad guess of the Mondays, this suggests that your Realia theme is already preprocessing something somewhere to use these non-standard templates, and that might be why this isn't working here...

Comment: err, case of the Mondays :)